# Not setting ManualResetEvent to true

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

```
 List<ManualResetEvent> doneEventsList = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

 productBuilders.ForEach(productBuilder =>
            {
                doneEventsList.Add(productBuilder.GetDoneEvent());
                CustomThreadPool.getSingletonInstance.QueueUserWorkItem(productBuilder.GetAndMapProduct, new Object());
            });

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEventsList.ToArray());
```

I have small doubt on above code,

Lets say `CustomThreadPool` has List of 21 instances of '`Thread`'class and '`productBuilders`' has 3 builders. In this case , thread acquired count will be '3' from CustomThreadPool . Lets say, If I am not setting 'Set()/true' on `ManualResetEvent` object in any of that 3 '`GetAndMapProduct`' calls, , what will happen to those 3 threads. I mean if I am looping above code 7 times and acquiring 3 thread every time and not setting `ManualResetEvent`, cannot I use the CustomThreadPool class at all?, because of CustomThreadPool assumes all (7*3) threads are busy with their working and it doesnt have any free thread to assign?;

Comment: The job of a threadpool scheduler, even a custom one, is to *not* let all threads start at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any code to suggest that the `ManualResetEvent` affects those 3 threads in *any* way.  The only thing they would affect (based on your code) would be the *current* thread via the call to `WaitAll`, and based on what you've provided and described, that would be a deadlock.

If you're only managing different threads in the same process, I would also recommend using `ManualResetEventSlim` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx) instead, especially if what you're doing in `GetAndMapProduct` is fairly quick.  But, it's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish.